# how to change date format from utc

Tags: javascript, date, fetch-api

How can I change date format received from a API when a date comes in UTC format
so that the date will be day/month/year?

```
fetch('https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches/next')
.then(result => result.json())
.then((res) => {
    console.log(res.launch_date_local);
})
```

Looks like I found the solution to this, thanks to all that posted,
but this works for me:

```
fetch('https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches/next')
.then(result => result.json())
.then((res) => {
    (res.launch_date_local);
                                                                      
            const date = Date.parse(res.launch_date_local);                            
            console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB').format(date));   
      });
```

Comment: Load it into a `Date` (`new Date(res.launch_date_local)`) and use its accessor methods like `getFullYear`, `getMonth` (note it starts with 0 and not 1!) and `getDate`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: UTC is not a format, it's a time standard. If the date is not in one of the two formats recognised by ECMA-262, then using Date.parse is fraught and likely to produce errors in some clients. Also see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
fetch('https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches/next')
.then(result => result.json())
.then((res) => {
    const date = new Date(res.launch_date_local);
    const day = date.getDay();
    const month = date.getMonth();
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    console.log(`${day}/${month}/${year}`);
})
```

Comment: `date.getDay()` should be `date.getDate()` and `date.getMonth()` should be `date.getMonth() + 1`. Likely the values should also be zero padded to 2 digits.